# Eclipse application not exporting

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have a legacy Eclipse based RCP application which has been working perfectly. The original developer has long since left the company and I have been tasked with updating some hard-coded connection strings and deploying that onto a new server.

Not much from a Java background, I read the tutorial for building and deploying RCP applications. Seems straight forward enough, ensured that all the plug-ins are there in the product configuration, checked the JDK version and all the usual gotchas.

However, when running the exe after export and deploy, it fails with Application ID not found in registry. Upon digging further, noticed that the "Application" has not been exported into the Plug-ins folder.

How do I ensure that the updated application does get exported? Any idea on how I can fix this?

Thanks,B

Comment: Clarification: BTW, the plug-in.xml has the product configuration entry in it.                                         <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="analytics.application"
            name="AM">

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to say anything. Which of the several RCP export methods are you using? If you are using an xxx.product file what are its contents?

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for responding. I'm using a product file to export. BTW, when I try to launch the application within Eclipse Mars, I get the same error. The dependencies page shows 3 plug-ins marked with a red. The application plug-in, jTDS_JDBC, de.vogella.freechart.libs. Even after manually copying these to the plug-ins folder, I still get the same error.

Comment: If you have Eclipse projects for any of those dependencies they should be in your Eclipse workspace. If you just have plugins for the dependencies they should be part of your target platform.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you for your response. To include them in the target platform, I'd look at Run Configuration and add them as External Jars? Is that correct?

Comment: No, Preferences > Plug-in Development > Target Platform [see here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html). An Eclipse RCP never uses external jars.

Comment: Thanks again @greg-449 Here is the problem though. The RCP application is using 6 jars as dependencies. 2 of them are showing up as missing. They are de.vogella.jfreechart.libs and jTDS_JDBC. When I press "Add" on the Dependencies screen, it is blank. If I create a new target platform and add these 2, these are enabled and the other 2 pertaining to RCP i.e org.eclipse.ui.views,org.eclipse.ui.console,org.eclipse.birt,org.eclipse.birt.engine are disabled.  Any idea why the "Add" plug-ins window will show blank? How can I add all 6 and enable them?